# Sensitivity of Eigenvalues with invertibte matrix

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, perturbation-theory

Let $A$ a matrix having a set of eigenvectors $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ linearly independent with $\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\}$ eigenvalues associated. Let $\lambda$ eigenvalue of the perturbed matrix $A+ \delta A$. Prove that $\lambda$ satisfies the following inequality.

$$|\lambda - \lambda_i| \leq K(P) \|\delta A\| \text{ for } i=1,\ldots,n$$

where $K(P):= \|P^{-1}\|\cdot \|P\| $  the condition number of a matrix $P$, and $\|\delta A\| $ is the norm of the perturbation of $A$.

Comment: Is $P$ an arbitrary matrix? If so, you should try proving that $|\lambda - \lambda_i| \le ||\delta A||$. Assuming $A$ is full rank, here's a way to do this - Let the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$ be $u$. Note that $\{v_i\}_{i = 1, \dots, n}$ is a basis. Now expand the equation $(A+\delta A) u = \lambda u$ in terms of the aforementioned basis, rearrange a little, and take inner product with $v_i$.

Comment: Notice the proper way to include {curly braces} INSIDE of MathJax, as in $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$.  I edited accordingly and did some other copy-editing of MathJax notation. $\qquad$

Comment: P is an orthogonal matrix